Looking to combine LoRa with Gaussian Frequency-Shift Keying Mode
Question originally asked here.
I'm looking to increase the throughput of my LoRa signal by using GFSK. I'm new to LoRa and have no experience managing radio signals. I'm a programmer though and would like to develop firmware for my LoRa devices. Is there any good starting points as suggestions?

THis is what performance you can expect https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Juha-Petajajarvi/publication/315119434_Performance_of_a_low-power_wide-area_network_based_on_LoRa_technology_Doppler_robustness_scalability_and_coverage/links/58cf9941aca272335519403c/Performance-of-a-low-power-wide-area-network-based-on-LoRa-technology-Doppler-robustness-scalability-and-coverage.pdf

Searching 1st hit found here  https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-wireless/lora-config-at-433mhz/td-p/124237

Good resources to read, thanks. If I could up vote your replies I would.

have fun...    ...

I'm looking to increase the throughput of my LoRa signal by using GFSK but lora is a linear modulation spread spectrum technique. How do you envision you adapt that to GFSK? This seems to me to be impossible.
